# How many versions of the Android SDK do I actually NEED installed?

Tags: android, android-studio

I only have a 128GB SSD in my work laptop and I'm running on empty. The Android SDK directory is sucking up a ton of space (18GB).

I have a lot of old SDK versions installed.. do I need them anymore?  Or is the latest version enough?  I already have a lot of versions skipped, so I feel like it might be safe to delete some of the others.

For example, I have 4.0.3 (API 15) installed, but not 4.1.2 (API 16).  Is it safe to remove everything below 5.1.1 (API 22), regardless of my build targets?

Comment: Just 1 is enough (usually latest)

Comment: You can pretty easily add and remove these.  If there's concern about suddenly needing one (for example, to build a project handed over by someone else without changing its settings) without opportunity to re-download, backup the ones you are removing to a USB stick or external drive.

Answer (score 1):

You **need** just one to run the developer and it will compile with that version, if you want special compatibility with one specific version of Android you should test that app compiled with that version, and to compile with one version you need to download the sdk. But as long as you work fine with the last one and have (some) devices to test the app, just keep that and the extra libraries (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

One thing that makes the SDK folder explode is the system images. These are needed when you want to run AVD emulator and each version comes with variations (armeabi, intel, tv, etc). If you don't need to run emulators or just run specific versions then you should delete these.